# How do I convert MySQL that uses group by and order by clauses to T-SQL query?

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-server-2000, sql-order-by

I've got the following MySQL query that I would like to translate so it works in MSSQL:

```
SELECT  *
FROM 
(
    SELECT      *
    FROM        ranking
    ORDER BY    rank_no ASC
            ,   effective_dt DESC
) AS sorted_rank
WHERE       sorted_rank.rank_id = 1950
GROUP BY    sorted_rank.rank_no
LIMIT 10
```

I've spent an afternoon fiddling but I keep running into problems with GROUP BY and aggregates and all kinds of other errors.

To add a further spanner in the works, the ranking table DOES NOT have a primary key, and I think it may be required to get this working...

*Server Version*: **Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.2039**

*Schema*:

```
rank_id         int(11)
week_id         int(11)
rider_id        int(11)
year_no         int(11)
rank_no         int(11)
effective_dt    datetime
lastupdate_dt   datetime
point_no        float
average_no      float  
result_qy       int(11)
```

*Dataset*:

```
INSERT INTO `ranking` (`id`, `rank_id`, `week_id`, `rider_id`, `year_no`, `rank_no`,  `effective_dt`, `lastupdate_dt`, `point_no`, `average_no`,  `result_qy`)
VALUES
(244, 1950, 417, 72253, 2007, 1, '2006-09-03 00:00:00', '2006-09-01 01:45:00', 2559.19, 426.53, 5),
(108, 1950, 426, 72253, 2007, 1, '2006-11-05 00:00:00', '2006-11-01 05:59:00', 2559.19, 426.53, 5),
(340, 1950, 386, 21767, 2006, 1, '2006-01-29 00:00:00', '2006-11-29 13:31:00', 3256.25, 814.06, 4),
(178, 1950, 420, 60369, 2007, 2, '2006-09-24 00:00:00', '2006-09-26 06:31:00', 2315.86, 385.98, 4),
(166, 1950, 417, 60369, 2007, 2, '2006-09-03 00:00:00', '2006-09-01 01:45:00', 2315.86, 385.98, 4),
(109, 1950, 426, 60369, 2007, 2, '2006-11-05 00:00:00', '2006-11-01 05:59:00', 2315.86, 385.98, 4),
(110, 1950, 426, 49428, 2007, 3, '2006-11-05 00:00:00', '2006-11-01 05:59:00', 2191.19, 365.2, 4),
(227, 1950, 417, 49428, 2007, 3, '2006-09-03 00:00:00', '2006-09-01 01:45:00', 2191.19, 365.2, 4),
(409, 1950, 388, 19570, 2006, 3, '2006-02-12 00:00:00', '2006-11-29 13:31:00', 3106.26, 776.57, 4),
(72, 1950, 399, 47036, 2006, 4, '2006-04-30 00:00:00', '2006-11-29 13:33:00', 1038.02, 346.01, 3),
(413, 1950, 388, 55533, 2006, 4, '2006-02-12 00:00:00', '2006-11-29 13:31:00', 2835.3, 708.83, 4),
(111, 1950, 426, 64517, 2007, 4, '2006-11-05 00:00:00', '2006-11-01 05:59:00', 2001.68, 333.61, 4),
(112, 1950, 426, 72379, 2007, 5, '2006-11-05 00:00:00', '2006-11-01 05:59:00', 1677.32, 279.55, 6),
(263, 1950, 420, 27123, 2007, 5, '2006-09-24 00:00:00', '2006-09-26 06:31:00', 1607.31, 267.88, 4),
(415, 1950, 388, 45738, 2006, 5, '2006-02-12 00:00:00', '2006-11-29 13:31:00', 2744.03, 686.01, 4),
(113, 1950, 426, 27123, 2007, 6, '2006-11-05 00:00:00', '2006-11-01 05:59:00', 1607.31, 267.88, 4),
(575, 1950, 420, 50354, 2007, 6, '2006-09-24 00:00:00', '2006-09-26 06:31:00', 1148.84, 191.47, 2),
(422, 1950, 388, 39070, 2006, 6, '2006-02-12 00:00:00', '2006-11-29 13:31:00', 2626.51, 656.63, 4),
(114, 1950, 426, 65745, 2007, 7, '2006-11-05 00:00:00', '2006-11-01 05:59:00', 1576.83, 262.8, 4),
(293, 1950, 388, 42127, 2006, 7, '2006-02-12 00:00:00', '2006-11-29 13:31:00', 2614.46, 653.62, 4),
(576, 1950, 420, 32669, 2007, 7, '2006-09-24 00:00:00', '2006-09-26 06:31:00', 1133.15, 188.86, 2),
(577, 1950, 420, 23242, 2007, 8, '2006-09-24 00:00:00', '2006-09-26 06:31:00', 1107.79, 184.63, 2),
(199, 1950, 420, 60322, 2007, 8, '2006-09-24 00:00:00', '2006-09-26 06:31:00', 1390.22, 231.7, 3),
(115, 1950, 426, 54984, 2007, 8, '2006-11-05 00:00:00', '2006-11-01 05:59:00', 1532.8, 255.47, 3),
(578, 1950, 420, 41116, 2007, 9, '2006-09-24 00:00:00', '2006-09-26 06:31:00', 1096.64, 182.77, 2),
(116, 1950, 426, 72386, 2007, 9, '2006-11-05 00:00:00', '2006-11-01 05:59:00', 1442.49, 240.41, 6),
(74, 1950, 399, 32669, 2006, 9, '2006-04-30 00:00:00', '2006-11-29 13:33:00', 817.64, 272.55, 3),
(818890, 1950, 1167, 77510, 0, 10, '2012-01-13 00:00:00', '2012-01-13 11:11:00', 1464.43, 366.11, 4),
(825706, 1950, 1168, 70324, 0, 10, '2012-01-20 00:00:00', '2012-01-20 11:05:00', 1259.38, 314.85, 2),
(826752, 1950, 1170, 75911, 0, 10, '2012-02-01 00:00:00', '2012-02-01 12:58:00', 1237.95, 309.49, 3);
```

*Correct output*:

```
1950    426     72253   2007    1   2006-11-05 00:00:00  2006-11-01 05:59:00     2559.19    426.53      5
1950    426     60369   2007    2   2006-11-05 00:00:00  2006-11-01 05:59:00     2315.86    385.98      4
1950    426     49428   2007    3   2006-11-05 00:00:00  2006-11-01 05:59:00     2191.19    365.2       4
1950    426     64517   2007    4   2006-11-05 00:00:00  2006-11-01 05:59:00     2001.68    333.61      4
1950    426     72379   2007    5   2006-11-05 00:00:00  2006-11-01 05:59:00     1677.32    279.55      6
1950    426     27123   2007    6   2006-11-05 00:00:00  2006-11-01 05:59:00     1607.31    267.88      4
1950    426     65745   2007    7   2006-11-05 00:00:00  2006-11-01 05:59:00     1576.83    262.8       4
1950    426     54984   2007    8   2006-11-05 00:00:00  2006-11-01 05:59:00     1532.8     255.47      3
1950    426     72386   2007    9   2006-11-05 00:00:00  2006-11-01 05:59:00     1442.49    240.41      6
1950    1170    75911   0       10  2012-02-01 00:00:00  2012-02-01 12:58:00     1237.95    309.49      3
```

Comment: Why do you grouping by `rank_no`? Do you want to get SUM of some field of `ranking` along with the same `rank_no`? Please, provide `ranking` table structure.

Comment: The values of rank_no are 1,2,3,4 etc, but each number can appear more than once (1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,etc)  

I **only** want the latest row for each possible rank_no, hence the GROUP BY

Comment: What columns `ranking` table has?

Comment: @Andy sounds like this is a bigger problem. A table without a primary key is probably not a very good design. Could you please post the table definition. Also get rid of the LIMIT it is not supported by MSSQL. You would need to do a TOP 10. How do you identify the latests rank_no? The group by is NOT identifying the latest rank_no it is simply removing the duplicates by grouping items 1,1,1 as 1.

Comment: I think the relevant ones are shown in the query, but I've added the schema to the original post.

Comment: @Namphibian - the latest rank_no is discovered by sorting by effective_dt  DESC in the sub query

Comment: @Andy sorry misseed the effective_dt in the group by clause.

Comment: @Andy SergeanT's example is working for me. Please try it as it is probably your best bet on SQL 2000

Comment: @Siva: Thanks, it seems to be a coincidence that it works with the sample dataset, running it on the full table (~900000 records) returns rank_no 730,731,732,755,786,787,788,797,809,810 but I can't see *why* this would be the case. I can upload the full dataset somewhere I guess...

Comment: @Siva: The query returns 1, shall I post the data?

Comment: @Siva: AHAH! I realised that the dataset I provided doesn't include multiple rank_id (the real data does), this lead me to realise that the sub query is "leaking" over to pull other, later ranks.

Adding "AND r_inner.rank_id = 1950" to the sub query fixes this. If you update your answer I will mark it as the solution :)

Thanks HEAPS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## SQL Server 2000 and above

Based on your requirement, you need to find the most recent effective date within each rank. To achieve, you need to write a sub query that would fetch the maximum effective date for a given rank and then compare it with the date in the row to filter down to the required results. This will work in all versions from SQL Server 2000 and above.

Following query has been tested in SQL Server 2000.

[**Click here to view the demo in SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/917db/16)

*Script*:

```
SELECT  
TOP 10  id
    ,   rank_id
    ,   week_id
    ,   rider_id 
    ,   year_no
    ,   rank_no
    ,   effective_dt 
    ,   lastupdate_dt 
    ,   point_no  
    ,   average_no 
    ,   result_qy
FROM    ranking r_outer
WHERE   rank_id = 1950
AND     effective_dt = 
        (
            SELECT  MAX(effective_dt)
            FROM    ranking r_inner
            WHERE   r_inner.rank_no = r_outer.rank_no
            AND     r_inner.rank_id = 1950
        )
ORDER BY rank_no;
```

## SQL Server 2005 and above

You need to use **`RANK`** function that would partition the results by `rank_no` column and sort each partition by `rank_no` followed by `effective_dt` in descending order. Each sorted partition section will be assigned a rank value like 1, 2, 3 etc. You are interested in only the first rank of each of these partition groups. So, hence the outer SELECT to filter the results by `rank_num = 1`.

*RANK* function is supported only in *SQL Server 2005 and above*.

[**Click here to view demo in SQL Fiddle using SQL Server 2012.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/917db/3)

Script:

```
SELECT
TOP 10      id 
        ,   rank_id
        ,   week_id
        ,   rider_id 
        ,   year_no
        ,   rank_no
        ,   effective_dt 
        ,   lastupdate_dt 
        ,   point_no  
        ,   average_no 
        ,   result_qy
FROM
(
    SELECT  id 
        ,   rank_id
        ,   week_id
        ,   rider_id 
        ,   year_no
        ,   rank_no
        ,   effective_dt 
        ,   lastupdate_dt 
        ,   point_no  
        ,   average_no 
        ,   result_qy
        ,   RANK() OVER(
                    PARTITION BY rank_no 
                    ORDER BY rank_no, effective_dt DESC) rownum
    FROM    ranking r
    WHERE   r.rank_id = 1950
) t1 
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Comment: I don't seem to have RANK(), which means I am not on SQL Server 2005 (I realise I should have mentioned that)

Apart from that, this solution looks exactly what I need!

Is there a way around my lack of RANK()?

Comment: do a select @@version please. All of our solutions will not work on SQL 2000 and below.

Comment: @Namphibian - Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.2039

Again, very sorry for not posting that info originally!

Comment: @Siva you beat me to it and I used simple row number but yes this is one way to do it. Nice to see people using the SQL rank functions.

Comment: @Andy you need to seriously look at a upgrade then. SQL2000 is not supported any more and also it is extremely vulnerable to attacks as it is not maintained any more. The query in SQL 2000 is going to be a pain as well.

Comment: @Namphibian - To give you a bit of background, this is an external database which I do not control. There is a current system which *does* extract and display this data, but I am not able to have access to the source code to find out how they are putting these queries together.

I'm pretty out of my depth here, hence coming to SO for your expert help :)

I don't want to waste any more of your time though, so I can push back and explain that upgrading the server is going to be beneficial for the client going forward...

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend to use sub-query in `WHERE` clause to fetch record with maximum `effective_dt` (assuming that values are unique within one rank_no, I guess it is a datetime):

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM ranking R
WHERE R.rank_id = 1950 AND 
    R.effective_dt = (SELECT MAX(effective_dt) from ranking R2 WHERE R2.rank_no = R.rank_no AND R2.rank_id = R.rank_id)
ORDER BY R.rank_no
```

Comment: Okay, this doesn't work, but I realise you were shooting into the dark - I've updated the question with a sample dataset and the expected output. Thanks for your time so far!

Answer (score 0):

Just a note of caution without a primary key or clustered on this table it is going to be damned slow when the data grows. I would seriously recommend that you find out which fields are supposed to be keys. A table without a clustered index is a heap and they have no order(generally stored in the order of which they are inserted).

You can try the following query as well.

```
/*
    This CTE will sort the table into a usable structure. To see what it does run the select statement seperately.
*/
;WITH CTERankID
AS
(

SELECT  *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rank_no ORDER BY effective_Dt DESC) AS RowNo        
FROM ranking

)
SELECT  TOP 10   
    rank_id
    ,week_id
    ,year_no
   ,rank_no
   ,effective_dt
   ,lastupdate_dt
   ,point_no
   ,average_no
   ,result_qy
   ,rowno
FROM CTERankID AS rankTable
WHERE rankTable.RowNo=1
AND rankTable.rank_id = 1950
```

Hopefully it will help a little. PS This will not work in MySQL as MySQL does not support CTE's.

Comment: As with my reply to @Siva, I don't seem to have ROW_NUMBER() which means I can't use this solution.

I didn't know that SQL Server version would be an issue or I would have mentioned that in my original question, I feel bad for wasting your time :(